# Over $SET$ category, a relation R there is a contractible pair of morphisms $f,g$ if and only if $[x]$ has one element $x_{*}$ such...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

If I am over $SET$ category , I want to prove that given a relation R there is a contractible pair of morphisms $(f,g)$ if and only if every equivalence class $[x]$ has one element $x_{*}$ such  $xRx´$ if and only if $xRx_{*}$ and $x_{*}Rx´$

Definition.- A parallel pair of morphism $f,g:A$ $\rightarrow$ $B$ is contractible if there is a morphism $t:B$  $\rightarrow$ $A$ such  $ft$ = $1_{B}$ and $gtf=gtg$

Can anyone help me out by sketching a proof of the statement since im still new in categories?

I was thinking in  think the elements of the equivalnce class $[x]$ as morphisms between objects  $A,B$ of $SET$ so this way the morphism $t$ can be viewed as the element $x_{*}$ but this seems to be a very particular case of the statement.

Thanks, I really need to understand the proof of these as statement as soon as possible.

Comment: The problem is missing some context. A contractible pair of morphisms between which sets? Probably $f,g:A\times A\to A/R$, where $R$ is a relation on $A$?

Comment: The contractible morphisms are f and g over set A to set B in SET category as written in definition

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I was asking about. What do $A$ and $B$ have to do with $R$?

Comment: I dont know, i was tniking in relation between sets in form a categorical viewpoint as spans, but I dont know this will work

Comment: I guess, rather $B$ would be the base set and $A=R$, and we have $(f,g):R\to B\times B$.

Comment: Do we assume that $R$ is already an equivalence relation?